# Uniqueness of Powers

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently reading Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. The solutions manual uses a theorem in a way that I don't fully understand.

**Theorem 1.21** For every real $x >0$ and every integer $n>0$, there is one and only one positive real $y$ such that $y^n = x$.

**The solution manual uses it in this context:** Suppose $m^{nq} = m^{pq}$ where $m >0$ and $n, m, q $ are integers greater than $0$. Then by Theorem 1.21, we can take the $q$th root and end up with $m^n = m^p$.

I have a feeling of why the theorem can be used here, but these two situations still feel kind of different. Can someone perhaps help me see this?

Comment: The theorem as stated is not correct, unless y is also positive. Both situations are the same though, if you take  $m^{n}$  as y and q as n :  $(m^{n})^{q}=(m^{p})^{q}$  thus $m^{n}=m^{p}$

Comment: @WNG In the textbook, it says "positive real $y$"; OP mistakenly omitted a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $x=m^{nq}=m^{pq}$ is a positive real. By definition, we have $(m^n)^q = x$ as well as $(m^p)^q=x$. But Theorem 1.21 asserts that there is a unique $y$ such that $y^q=x$, so these two numbers $m^n$ and $m^p$ must be the same.